# $E(M_{n\wedge \tau}) = E(M_0)$ implies $M$ is a martingale

Tags: probability, probability-theory, martingales

$(M_n)_{n\geq 0}$ is an adapted family such that $E|M_n|<\infty$, then, I need to show that $E(M_{n\wedge \tau}) = E(M_0)$ implies $M$ is a martingale, for every stopping $\tau$.

Honestly, I do not know how to start. Any hint? Thanks

Comment: Hint: have a look at Doob's Optional Stopping [Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optional_stopping_theorem)

Comment: But this theorem gives me the other direction, isn't it? I am assuming that $E(M_{n\wedge \tau)} = E(M_0)$ holds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $A \in \mathcal{F}_k$, we need to show that $\mathbb{E}[\chi_A \cdot M_k] = \mathbb{E}[\chi_A \cdot M_{k+1}]$.

Consider $\tau = k + \chi_{A}$, this is clearly a stopping time. Therefore $\mathbb{E}[M_\tau] = \mathbb{E}[M_0] = \mathbb{E}[M_k]$, i.e. $$ \mathbb{E}[M_k] = \mathbb{E}[M_k \chi_{A^c} + M_{k+1}\chi_A]$$ which implies our thesis.

Comment: $\tau = k\chi_A$, isn't it?

Comment: No! $\tau = k+1$ in $A$ and $\tau = k$ in $A^c$

Comment: Oh!, now I completely understand. Thank you very much.

Comment: Where do you use the submartingale hypothesis?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any submartingale hypothesis, so I am not using it

Comment: Oh, it's true. I probably said so because today I had in mine a very similar problem: M submartingale and $E(M_n) = E(M_0)$ for every $n\geq 0$, then $M$ is a martingale. I got confused. But now everything it's clear.

Answer (score 1):

This is some kind of variation of no-arbitrage principle.
So, for any $k<n$, we define the following time:
$$\tau_k:=
    \begin{cases}
      k, & \text{if}\ M_{k} \ge \mathbb{E}(M_{k+1}|F_k) \\
      k+1, & \text{other wise}
    \end{cases}
$$
Clearly, $\tau_k$ is a stopping time.
On the other hand we have:
$$ \mathbb{E}(M_{k}) = \mathbb{E}(M_0)= \mathbb{E}( M_{n \wedge \tau_k})= \mathbb{E}( M_k \mathbb{1}_{\ M_{k} \ge \mathbb{E}(M_{k+1}|F_k)} +M_{k+1} \mathbb{1}_{\ M_{k} < \mathbb{E}(M_{k+1}|F_k)}  )   $$
Which implies $\mathbb{P}( M_k < \mathbb{E}(M_{k+1}|F_k) )=0$
Vice versa, we have:
$$\mathbb{P}( M_k > \mathbb{E}(M_{k+1}|F_k) )=0$$
Hence,
$$ \mathbb{E}(M_{k+1}|F_k)= M_k$$
Thus, the conclusion.

Comment: Thank you very much. What a clever construction. Very useful!